# Is there a fix for iframe preventing clicks on a page when working in React?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

Apparently this is a rare problem because I'm having trouble finding evidence of other people having it. I'm working on learning React and while building an app I keep running into this problem where clicking anything on a page doesn't work. The solution is to go into the browser's console and delete this iframe element. Once I do that, everything works fine. But I don't want to have to do that continuously, and also I'm just really curious at this point. Is there maybe a library to install or update? Not sure what would be helpful to look at, so I'll put my package.json and a screenshot of the console in here. If I delete that iframe element in red, everything would be fine. When a page is working, that iframe element isn't there in the first place. I haven't been able to figure out when it's going to be there and when it won't be, except it won't be when I first start it up. [image]

```
{
  "name": "scenic",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "cra-template": "1.0.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5"
  }
}
```